# postback of button click not working with <%= %>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am using the below method of calling the click event of buttton in javascript.

```
__doPostBack('<%= btn_hid.UniqueID %>');
```

but this is leading me to another error

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

can you please suggest me any other way to call the click event of button in javascript during postback??

Comment: Why not use button onclientclick method?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `click method` based on `GetElementById` method

```
document.GetElementById('<%= btn_hid.ClientID %>').click()
```

Comment: i want the button click event to be fired directly after the page load through javascript without actually clicking the button.

Comment: you embed this script in javascript function and call this function on load event of page

Comment: This is not leading me to the correct solution. I am implementing Facebook connect and the part of the code is :...  if (flag != 'False') {
                            __doPostBack('<%= btn_hid.UniqueID %>');
                                     } ...but the <%= %> is leading me to another error "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)." How can i solve both the problem along with postback of button click event